# annotation exception in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, subclass, superclass

I am trying to establish a one-to-many relation between Professor and Loan objects. Professor is a subclass of User object. Thus, I have created a user object which is necessarily a professor object.

```
private User professor
```

When I run the program, I get the following annotation exception.

> @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.csu.library.model.Loan.professor references an unknown entity: com.csu.library.model.User

Can anyone help what is wrong?

Comment: Can you post your Hibernate configuration?

Comment: should mean that User class is not annotated as @Entity; but your code or configuration may have other problems, try to add the relevant parts to your question

Comment: have you properly annotated User? If so, are you sure you have configured Hibernate to lookup that class? If so, are you sure that the JAR containing the User class is in classpath when running?

Comment: Yeah, my class is properly annotated. Just my hibernate class wasn't properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add you annotated as @Entity in your entity class and configured in `persistence.xml`

Comment: I did. It was configuration problem. I didn't map the classes. Silly me!